# Roles/permissions itemisation?

Tags: sitecore

I've been looking for a while now and have done a number of deployments for roles and permissions manually, but is there any way to create a package (or equivalent of) for Roles/Permissions in Sitecore?

It's a seriously tedious job to manually deploy new roles with permissions when you don't have the option to do a full deploy from one environment to the next.

Just curious if anyone's managed to do this or has a way of making this easier?

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

User and roles can be added to packages.
In the package designer, there is a "Security Accounts" button in the Add ribbon that enables you to add users/roles to the package.

As for permissions, they are stored in the items that they are set on.
So to deploy the permissions, you should add the items to the package.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I guess I'd _like_ to be able to set the item level permissions for a role group and when I package the role up, so long as the items are there, have them come across with them. It's the ticking of boxes over and over when it's not possible to do a full re-deploy that takes the time and is a little frustrating.

Appreciate the assit

Comment: I agree that it would be nice to be able to set which fields you want to package. So you could select all content items and only the security fields for packaging. Makes a nice feature request :)