# Exporting user permissions?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Does anyone know of any way to export user and role permissions, and then re-import them on another copy of Sitecore?

I've had a search around, and bar writing a bit of code to do this, doesn't appear to be anything immediately available ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permissions are actually stored on the *items themselves*, not the Role or User objects. There are two ways to export the object like Stephen mentioned, perform the export/import on the item you granted/revoked access to, not the role or user.

Comment: It appears that this question was also asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553980/roles-permissions-itemisation/13300358

Comment: Thanks I guessed it was going to be something like this. Didn't find that other item when searching but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this .. you can make a Sitecore package and add them to that, the other way is to use Serialization which will write text files to disk that you can then restore into another sitecore instance.

The choice very much depends on how many users / roles you have to move. If its just a few, you can use a Sitecore package but if you have a lot you will probably want to use serialization to do it.

More info about each topic can be found here..

- [Serialization Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Serialization%20Guide.aspx)
- [Info on Packages](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Package%20Designer%20Administrator%20Guide.aspx)

Comment: Looks like serialization will let you export the users / roles, but will not keep the actual permissions on items / workflow themselves?